# What are the tradeoffs of using mongoid's has_and_belongs_to_many with inverse_of

Tags: mongoid

In the docs it says you can use inverse_of: nil but doesn't really describe the use case:
http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#has_and_belongs_to_many

I'm assuming it is useful in the case where one object would have a LOT of the other, so you can just skip that side entirely with inverse_of nil and save some storage space right?

So for example:

```
class Post
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
end

class Tag
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts, inverse_of: nil
end
```

A tag might belongs to hundreds or thousands of posts, but a post probably only has 5 tags or so.

So is this a good use case for it?  I assume you can still do

```
tag.posts
```

etc like normal, and the main trade off is that it changes the query from:

```
Post.find(tag.post_ids)
```

into

```
Post.where(tag_ids: tag.id)
```

If you have an index on tag_ids it seems like it would still be quite fast.  So maybe the best is something like:

```
class Post
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags, index: true
end

class Tag
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts, inverse_of: nil
end
```

Just want to check my thinking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You certainly got the use case right but example seems to be reworked upon. Your models should look like this:

```
class Post
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags, inverse_of: nil, index: true
end

class Tag
  # you don't want this side as a tag can be related to 1000s of posts
end
```

You can use the associations from posts but for tags you will have to create queries yourself.

```
post.tags                    # get tags for a post
Post.where(tag_ids: tag.id)  # find posts for a tag
```

Comment: Ok awesome, this makes more sense now what they meant by one sided - you don't setup the habtm on the other side.  Thanks @rubish I really appreciate it!

Comment: Just to follow up...do you know if there is an easy way to get the accessor methods setup on the `Tag` side.  I started defining my own `def posts`, `def posts=` etc but I realized there are quite a few more like `<<`, `push`, and the after callbacks when a post gets destroyed etc.  Figured there might be an easier way.  Thanks!

Comment: @BrianArmstrong Sorry, but I am not aware of an easy way out. Although you can try mongoid mailing list.